# How put together data in an array using php?

Tags: php, arrays

sorry if I don't ask correctly.

This is part of my table:

[image]

In `daoExcel.php` I have this function:

```
public function selectInconsistencias(){
                    
                    $aObjects=array();
                    $dbconn = new DBconnection();
                    $db = $dbconn->bdConnection();
                    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT rco_rut,rco_nombre,rco_marc, rco_estado FROM act_relcontrol");  
                                                                      
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    
                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                            $fecha = date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$row['rco_marc']), mktime(0, 0, 0)));
                            $aTransfer = new DaoTransferExcel();
                            $aTransfer->setRut($row['rco_rut']);
                            $aTransfer->setNombre($row['rco_nombre']);
                            $aTransfer->setFecha($fecha);
                            $aTransfer->setEstado($row['rco_estado']);
    
                            $aObjects[]=$aTransfer;
                    }
                
                    return $aObjects;
                    
            }
```

Then I return the results to `controllerExcel.pho` and I use the data in this function:

```
private function setDatosInconsistencias($datos){

        foreach($datos as $sKey=>$oValue){    
            $list[] = array('rut' => $oValue->getRut(),
                            'nombre' => $oValue->getNombre(),
                            'fecha' => $oValue->getFecha(),
                            'estado' => $oValue->getEstado(),
                            'count_ent' => '0',
                            'count_sal' => '0'
                            );
        }
        
        print_r($list);
        exit();
    }
```

> print_r($list);

Prints all the data from data base of this way:

[image]

Well, I need this:

Example 1:

I have this:

[image]

But I need only this:

[image]

Example 2:

I have this:

[image]

And I need only this:

[image]

Example 3:

I have this:

[image]

And I need only this:

[image]

So, I need count the 'M/Ent' and 'M/Sal' by day and I don't need `[estado]`.

Some advice of how do this?

Sorry by my english.

Comment: Loop across your array and delete the properties you do not need. Second use array_unique.

Comment: In your "Example 1" where is says "But I need only this:", the array key is 2. Do you also need to maintain this key in the result?

Comment: @Thefourthbird no I don't need maintain the key, I only need compress the results in one , but by day , for example with my examples the final array will be: [fecha] => 26/08/2015 [count_ent] => 2 [coun_sal] => 2][fecha]=>02/09/2015 [count_ent] => 3 [count_sal] = 1][fecha]=>25/08/2015 [count_ent] = 1 [count_sal] =1. with "rut" and "nombre" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your results in an array where you can use "fecha" as an array key.

In your foreach loop you remember the value of "estado" so you know which field to increment and then unset it from the array because you don't need it.

Then you can reference the `$result` array by "fecha" and increment the "count_sal" or "count_ent"

For example:

```
$result = array();
$list = array(
    22 => array(
        "rut" => "16.534.770-6",
        "nombre" => "Miguel Pichipillán S",
        "fecha" => "02/09/2015",
        "estado" => "M/Ent",
        "count_ent" => 0,
        "count_sal" => 0
    ),
    23 => array(
        "rut" => "16.534.770-6",
        "nombre" => "Miguel Pichipillán S",
        "fecha" => "02/09/2015",
        "estado" => "M/Ent",
        "count_ent" => 0,
        "count_sal" => 0
    ),
    24 => array(
        "rut" => "16.534.770-6",
        "nombre" => "Miguel Pichipillán S",
        "fecha" => "02/09/2015",
        "estado" => "M/Ent",
        "count_ent" => 0,
        "count_sal" => 0
    ),
    25 => array(
        "rut" => "16.534.770-6",
        "nombre" => "Miguel Pichipillán S",
        "fecha" => "02/09/2015",
        "estado" => "M/Sal",
        "count_ent" => 0,
        "count_sal" => 0
    ),
);

foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $estado = $value["estado"];
    $fecha = $value["fecha"];

    unset($value["estado"]);

    if (!isset($result[$fecha])) {
        $result[$fecha] = $value;
    }

    if ($estado === "M/Sal") {
        $result[$fecha]["count_sal"]++;
    }

    if ($estado === "M/Ent") {
        $result[$fecha]["count_ent"]++;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Will result in:

```
array (size=1)
  '02/09/2015' => 
    array (size=5)
      'rut' => string '16.534.770-6' (length=12)
      'nombre' => string 'Miguel Pichipillán S' (length=21)
      'fecha' => string '02/09/2015' (length=10)
      'count_ent' => int 3
      'count_sal' => int 1
```

[Demo with multiple dates](https://3v4l.org/B7rXR)

Comment: It's a lot of work if I want show only the days that have [count_ent] => 2 and [count_sal] => 2?.If you don't want or can't help me, don't care , you helped me a lot, thank you

Comment: @Jeanbf You can loop the $result and then check for the values of "count_ent" and "count_sal" and use unset if you want to remove the entry from the $result. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/ap8fa)